# Slow performance of search results PHP - MYSQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a website with a large database of reports (300K rows, 1.6 GB). And the search engine is taking really long to show the results.

The search is trhough 3 tables:

- The main table has the title of the report, the description and the table of content.
- The second table has the business sector of  each report (Automotive, mining, healthcare, etc)
- The 3th table has the country code of each report.

It comes up like this:

[image]

Before it was around 50 secs, now I splitted the database in 2 to get faster search performance, and now is taking around 30 secs, that is still a lot.

I think the problem should be in one of this queries, but I can't recognize where the mistake is.

Can you help me to see how can I optimize the queries? It's really important .I have tried different solutions and none of them has work.

Structure of main table:

```
Field            Type         Null Key Default Extra
id               int(12)      NO   PRI NULL    auto_increment
name             varchar(220) NO   MUL NULL  
data             date         NO       NULL  
publication_date date         NO   MUL NULL  
no_pages         int(12)      NO   MUL NULL  
description      text         NO       NULL  
table_content    text         NO       NULL  
type             varchar(120) NO   MUL NULL  
price            float        NO   MUL NULL  
currency         varchar(12)  NO   MUL NULL  
status           int(12)      NO   MUL NULL  
organizer_id     int(12)      NO   MUL NULL  
pic              varchar(80)  NO       NULL  
main_sec         varchar(80)  NO       NULL  
main_reg         varchar(80)  NO       NULL
```

INDEXES

```
Table   Non_unique Key_name         Seq_in_index Column_name      Collation Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment
reports 0          PRIMARY          1            id               A         129700      NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          publication_date 1            publication_date A         712         NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          price            1            price            A         584         NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          name_2           1            name             A         129700      NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          organizer_id     1            organizer_id     A         48          NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          type             1            type             A         162         NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          status           1            status           A         4           NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          currency         1            currency         A         4           NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          no_pages         1            no_pages         A         831         NULL        NULL            BTREE    
reports 1          name             1            name             NULL      1           NULL        NULL            FULLTEXT
```

CODE

```
<?
if (($cr=='' AND $cr_parent=='') OR ($cr!='' AND $sector!='')) {
$zapytanie_s = "SELECT count(DISTINCT u.id) AS ile_s, w.name_cat AS name_cat_s, t.id_cat AS id_cat_s FROM reports as u, sector_index_reports as t, sectors as w WHERE u.id = t.id_obiekt AND w.id = t.id_cat AND u.status!='0' $q $warunek2 $warunek3 $warunek4 $warunek5 $warunek6 $warunek7 GROUP BY w.name_cat ORDER BY ile_s DESC";
} else if ($cr!='' AND $sector_parent!='') {
$zapytanie_s = "SELECT count(DISTINCT u.id) AS ile_s, w.name_cat AS name_cat_s, t.id_cat AS id_cat_s FROM reports as u, sector_index_reports as t, sectors as w WHERE u.id = t.id_obiekt AND w.id = t.id_cat AND u.status!='0' $q $warunek2 $warunek3 $warunek4 $warunek5 $warunek6 $warunek7 GROUP BY w.name_cat ORDER BY ile_s DESC"; 
//echo $zapytanie_s;
} else {
$zapytanie_s = "SELECT count(DISTINCT u.id) AS ile_s, w.name_cat AS name_cat_s, u.main_sec AS id_cat_s FROM reports as u, country_index_reports as t, sectors as w WHERE u.id = t.id_obiekt AND w.id = u.main_sec AND u.status!='0' $q $warunek2 $warunek3 $warunek4 $warunek5 $warunek6 $warunek7 GROUP BY w.name_cat ORDER BY ile_s DESC";
}
$wynik_s = mysql_query($zapytanie_s);
//echo $zapytanie_s;
WHILE ($row_s = @mysql_fetch_array($wynik_s)) {
extract($row_s);  ?>
<div style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:25px;"><a href="./results.php?s=<? echo $s; ?>&ls=<? echo $ls; ?>&sortuj=<? echo $sortuj; ?>&typ=<? echo $typ; ?>&publish_date=<? echo $publish_date; ?>&sector=<? echo $id_cat_s; ?>&cr=<? echo $cr; ?><? echo $cr_parent; ?>&cr_parent=&sector_parent=&org_id=<? echo $org_id; ?>&keyword=<? echo $keyword; ?>" style="color:#000000"><? echo $name_cat_s; 
if ($sector=='' AND $cr_parent=='') { print ("&nbsp;($ile_s)"); } else if ($cr_parent!='') { print ("&nbsp;"); }  else { print ("&nbsp;($liczba_rekordow)"); } 
?></a> </div> 
<? } ?>
</div>
<? // } ?>
<? //if ($sector_parent=='') { ?>
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:20px;"><strong>|&nbsp;Countries/Regions: </strong> 
<? if ($cr!='') { ?>
<span class="dopaginacji" style="float:right; margin-top:-8px;"><a href="./results.php?s=<? echo $s; ?>&ls=<? echo $ls; ?>&sortuj=<? echo $sortuj; ?>&typ=<? echo $typ; ?>&publish_date=<? echo $publish_date; ?>&sector=<? echo $sector; ?>&cr=&cr_parent=&sector_parent=<? echo $sector_parent; ?>&org_id=<? echo $org_id; ?>&keyword=<? echo $keyword; ?>" style="color:#000000"><b>x</b> clear</span></a>
<? } ?>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; max-height:300px; overflow:auto; ">
<?
if ($sector=='' AND $sector_parent=='') {
$zapytanie_s = "SELECT count(DISTINCT u.id) AS ile_s, w.name_cat AS name_cat_s, t.id_cat AS id_cat_s FROM reports as u, country_index_reports as t, countries as w WHERE u.id = t.id_obiekt AND w.id = t.id_cat AND u.status!='0' $q $warunek2 $warunek3 $warunek4 $warunek5 $warunek6 $warunek7 GROUP BY w.name_cat ORDER BY ile_s DESC";
} else if ($cr!='' AND $sector!='') {
$zapytanie_s = "SELECT count(DISTINCT u.id) AS ile_s, nn.name_cat AS name_cat_s, u.main_reg AS id_cat_s FROM reports as u, sector_index_reports as t, countries as nn WHERE u.id = t.id_obiekt AND nn.id = u.main_reg AND u.status!='0' $q $warunek2 $warunek3 $warunek4 $warunek5 $warunek6 $warunek7 GROUP BY nn.name_cat ORDER BY ile_s DESC";
} else {
$zapytanie_s = "SELECT count(DISTINCT u.id) AS ile_s, w.name_cat AS name_cat_s, u.main_reg AS id_cat_s FROM reports as u, sector_index_reports as t, countries as w WHERE u.id = t.id_obiekt AND w.id = u.main_reg AND u.status!='0' $q $warunek2 $warunek3 $warunek4 $warunek5 $warunek6 $warunek7 GROUP BY w.name_cat ORDER BY ile_s DESC";
//echo $zapytanie_s;
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd show your database design and the indexes on the tables

Comment: also, you mention different solutions you tried. What were they? Just to avoid us from suggesting them if they did not make an impact.

Comment: Have you tried splitting up your code into segments, and running each segment?  That may identify the offending query (assuming the problem is a query).

Comment: please clean up your question and provide only the relevant code as well as better/cleaner table structure. This will enable people to help you faster and better.

Comment: If you have trouble with sql performance, you do **NOT** need to hide the relevant sql in a pile of utterly irrelevant php/html. Your code snippet is basically unreadable and also appears to vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Please just show us one actual SQL query that is slow, not the PHP code surrounding it that created it.

Comment: Especially not PHP looking like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to get all the suspected queries and you do an `explain select` in a database management studio like the MySQL Workbench.

This way you will see exactly what each query is doing and you will be able to adjust it accordingly.

You will probably be able to improve performance by using indexes on the items in your where clauses (not all of them of course as this would take too much space). Also instead of doing a

```
from table1, table2
```

try a `join`. It would really help if you supplied the queries as they are executed in the database (without the php variables) since this is probably the bottleneck.